# Facts about schizophrenia; Is the sufferer still accountable?

Tags: hadith, practical-islam, disability

Are those who suffer from mental disorders such as schizophrenia no longer accountable for prayer and other obligatory duties ?
Is there any hadith for satisfying the answer of this question  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on severity of the condition. If insane then will not earn sin:

> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "The Pen is lifted from the minor,
>   the insane person and the sleeper."
>
> https://sunnah.com/urn/1263610 https://sunnah.com/nasai/27/44
>   https://sunnah.com/urn/1263600